# RVM ignores my .ruby-gemset file

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I have a project with a `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` file. The `.ruby-version` file seems to be working, but not the `.ruby-gemset` file.

I've got the latest stable RVM:

```
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.25.27 (stable)
```

The files exist:

```
$ ls -la
-rw-r--r-- 1 {user} {group} 13 Jun 9 13:14 .ruby-gemset
-rw-r--r-- 1 {user} {group} 16 Jun 9 13:13 .ruby-version
...
```

The files have valid content (right?):

```
$ cat .ruby-version
ruby-1.9.3-p194

$ cat .ruby-gemset
my_gemset
```

The Ruby exists, and it loads correctly via the `.ruby-version`:

```
$ rvm list rubies
rvm rubies
    ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ i686 ]
    ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
=>  ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
...
```

But the gemset does not load (it's still set to `(default)`)!:

```
$ rvm gemset list
gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /Users/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
=> (default)
   global
   my_gemset
...
```

I'm on Mac OS X. Not sure if important, but I recently upgraded to OS X Mavericks. I also had recently upgraded RVM after encountering a variety of issues with my Ruby installation (`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enable` and then `rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p194`).

What am I missing? / What can I try?

---

**EDIT:** This is interesting. When I try to explicitly use a gemset, I get:

```
$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@my_gemset
Using /Users/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

That's unexpected. It's like the command is ignoring the gemset specifier?

```
$ rvm gemset use ruby-1.9.3-p194@my_gemset
Using ruby-1.9.3-p194@my_gemset with gemset default
```

That's also wrong. It's treating the `{ruby}@{gemset}` specifier as just a Ruby version. I guess I'm going to try nuking and reinstalling RVM.

---

**EDIT 2:** In the end, the only way I could get this to work again was to completely uninstall RVM (using `rvm implode`) and then re-install it with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`. I also had to re-install Ruby 1.9.3-p194.

I guess my installation had gotten messed up somehow. Not a very satisfying answer, but hopefully it will help someone in the future.

Comment: Is there also an .rvmrc file? That always takes precedence over the `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files.

Comment: @JohnFeminella No, there's no `.rvmrc` file.